# Import Neo4J data into Oracle relational database

Tags: oracle, neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I would like to keep the Neo4J database as the master database, and I would like to keep oracle relational database tables sincronized with Neo4J dat as a read-only Materialized View .

I only find links and articles explaining how to import relational data into Neo4j and not the other way around.

Conceptually I am looking for a kind of Materizalized View in Oracle using a Cypher Query as source. Maybe I could make a custom Merge program, mapping Oracle Tables to Cypher queries. Ideally I would like to run this program in Oracle (PLSQL).

Thanks in advance,

Comment: *"I only find links and articles explaining how to import relational data into Neo4j and not the other way around."* That's because it's usual to built write-path systems in transactional RDBMS databases and use graph DBs for read-path querying.

Comment: Of course, since Oracle 19c [the Spatial and Graph capability](https://www.oracle.com/a/tech/docs/spatial-and-graph-in-oracle-database-19c-preso.pdf) is included in [all editions of the database without additional licences](https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclespatial/spatial-now-free-with-all-editions-of-oracle-database). So you have the option of ditching neo4j and going with a pure Oracle solution. Probably that's not practical, but it's something to consider. (BTW I am familiar with neo4j and love Cypher query language, so this isn't Oracle fanboi spouting.)